# Postagens do Blogger em deslizamento horizontal

Tags: css, xml, blogger

Galera, eu sou novo aqui e quero uma ajuda com o Blogger, não consigo resolver um problema que a dias estou tentando, e se não houver um jeito então vou desistir. Eu não sei programar direito, mas estou tentando colocar as postagens do Blogger em deslizamento horizontal tanto para desktop quanto para mobile, como se fosse um tipo de slide das postagens, para ilustrar melhor que o eu quero, é fazer semelhante ao Facebook Instante Article(Artigos Instantâneos) com rolagem horizontal dos artigos, ou tem esse exemplo aqui http://jsfiddle.net/evqt871L/ que se assemelha também. Bom se estou pedindo muito peço-lhes desculpas, mas se há alguma jeito por favor me ajudem.

não é slide de imagens somente não é a postagem toda

```css
.container{
    padding:20px;
    border:dotted 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:auto;
}

.box{
    width:100px;
    height:180px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual é seu conhecimento em CSS?

Comment: conhecimento em css é intermediário

Comment: Ok, tente adicionar na pergunta o css do seu blogspot para que possamos pelo menos saber de onde começar a te ajudar.

Comment: coloquei mas não sei vai ajudar

Comment: alguém por favor?